# How do I use the result of an input box in another bit of my code?

Tags: vba, excel

So I am very new to VBA and coding and have been playing around writing very simple subs. The sub takes a sheet from a workbook, copies into a new workbook and then saves it. the problem is that I want to be able to specify the name it uses when it saves the document. I am using an input box, I just can't seem to get the code to accept the result. This is my code

```
Sub CC_Export()
Dim name As String
Dim Wb As Workbook

Set Wb = Workbooks("workbook1")
    Wb.Sheets("Sheet1").Copy
    name = InputBox("Enter Name of New Workbook", "New Workbook")
    ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs "name.xlsx", FileFormat:=51

End Sub
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your code is using the literal text "name.xlsx". To use the variable you need to concatenate its value into your text string

```
ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs name & ".xlsx", FileFormat:=51
```

Comment: Ah thank you! I knew there was a way, I spent ages looking around online for the fix. Thanks again

Answer (score 3):

**edited** to take advantage of implicit extension assumptions as per @Pawel Sotor answer and further reduce the code length

Rory gave you the solution

Just to throw in you can shorten down your code as follows:

```
Sub CC_Export()
    Workbooks("workbook1").Sheets("Sheet1").Copy
    ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs InputBox("Enter Name of New Workbook", "New Workbook"), FileFormat:=51
End Sub
```

Comment: Wow yes, that looks a lot better. Thank you for that

Answer (score 2):

Just replace the `"name.xlsx"` with `name`, so your code should look like this: `ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs name, FileFormat:=51`

Comment: Just want to point out that with this approach the user would have to provide the file extension in the `InputBox`

Comment: I have just checked this code and it worked without the extension. Excel takes the extension from the `FileFormat:=51` property.

Comment: You are absolutely right. I overlooked the `FileFormat` property.

Comment: Thank you, I will make sure to note down that I can skip the extension in the future if I have the right FileFormat property!